# Uploading Large file into Oracle database using tomcat web service

Tags: oracle, web-services, file-upload, tomcat7, heap-memory

I have an application that uses Tomcat 7.0 as a web service, and where my back end database is Oracle 11g. We use the application to upload huge files (e.g. avi, mp4, pdf etc) into our Oracle 11g database. I was able to increase the upload settings to allow up to 1.0 GB file size, however, I am now having problems uploading any files greater than 1.0 GB (especially video files). I am getting "File size too large" error whenever I try to upload > 2.0 GB. Please advise on what to configure to allow me to upload files up to 4.0 GB in size.

Comment: where do you get the `File size too large` error? Oracle or Tomcat? Also what is the data type of your column, is it BLOB ?

Comment: Column is BLOB. The error is thrown in the application. It is a vendor's application called GroupLink which uses Tomcat7 as web service. The backend is Oracle 11g,

Comment: From their documentation, they said to increase the max_allowed_packet in my.cnf of MySQL. But there is no parameter of that name in Oracle. Not sure how to configure it in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Remove the "thanks" comment.